# Display video description over the video view in android

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-videoview

Hi I am developing small android application in which I want to display some textual information over my video view same like youtube showing text content over the video and user can close that content.I am bit confuse to decide which approach I should take. Either use surfaceview or user video view Or user some custom video view with extended class. Ot just include text view with overlay on top of video view. Any one here already implemented this king of stuff can please help me to sort this situation. Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Try to use FrameLayout and put description Textview over VideoView.

Comment: Yeah I am also thinking that only.Just want to confirm is this the correct approach or creating custom video view class will be the good approach.

Comment: I think there is no need for creating custom video class just use FrameLayout.

Comment: Ok let me try and will let you know if it works.